# Changing nesting within an Angular 2 component template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a user-configurable layout where I believe I would need to change nesting of elements per configuration. I don't want multiple templates, as this would be a chore to maintain, but I would like to know if there is some way in Angular 2 to define a parent element whose child elements will display weather or not the parent element is displayed. So if I have:

```
<parent>
    <child />
</parent>
```

I would like to use some sort of toggle to remove the `parent` element from the display list without losing it's `child`. So upon toggling off, `child` would become a child of `parent`'s parent.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the classes specifically, or components with view-children?

Comment: I will answer with a different approach if you actually need to remove that parent element from the DOM.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify. I am not trying to toggle the class, but rather remove the parent element without losing its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing to match the new question:

I'm not aware of any option to allow you to this easily.  A simple solution that may not be comprehensive enough for your application:

```
<parent *ngIf="parentCondition">
    <child />
</parent>
<child *ngIf="!parentCondition" />
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!